# ngAnimate : How can I do "+300px" on click?

Tags: angularjs, css-animations, ng-animate

Today I'm working on animations with ngAnimate (AngularJS).

I have a div and I want it to move to the right when I click on a button.
With jQuery it's easy you can do :

```
.animate({marginLeft: "+=300"}, 500);
```

But I don't know how to do that with ngAnimate.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) is the example for `ng-style`:

```
<input type="button" value="set color" ng-click="myStyle={color:'red'}">
<input type="button" value="set background" ng-click="myStyle={'background-color':'blue'}">
<input type="button" value="clear" ng-click="myStyle={}">
<br/>
<span ng-style="myStyle">Sample Text</span>
<pre>myStyle={{myStyle}}</pre>
```

You can create a variable in your controller, increase the value for the margin on click and update the style.

Comment: But how would you animate? The OP wants to animate the style as well

Comment: You can use `translate` in your style?

Comment: Thank you for your answer : I tried
`$scope.slideStyle="-webkit-transform:translateX(+300px)";`
But it doesn't work (and I think I'm totally wrong)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `transform`? Use a class with `transform: translate3d(300)` and apply the class while animating

```
<div class="animate-slide" ng-show="slide" ng-click="slide=!slide">
  <center>AngularJS ng-animate<center>
</div>
```

This approach has an additional benefit that the animation happens on GPU and he frame rate is not affected

**EDIT:**

See this codepen for the exact implementation: http://codepen.io/agramian/pen/JCloz

Comment: First of all : thak you for your help. Then ... I have to admit I don't really know how to do that. For me, once I applied the class I won't be able to use it again.

Comment: Ok thank you. I think I got it but can I add multiple times the same class (if I clicked 5 times on my button I added 1500px to margin-left of my div)

Comment: In that case use a scope variable to store the current marginLeft and assign that to style using `ng-style`. Increment it on every click

Comment: I tried that : `<div ng-style="{'margin-left':'{{(-current*300)-50}}px'}>"` (current is the variable increasing each click). In the web inspector I have for current =0 : `{'margin-left':'-50px'}` so it works. BUT my element didn't move an inch

Comment: Found a way to deal with it but I would like to know your thoughts about it and I'm still hoping an answer for the previous problem. Edit on my post